# php command line exec() multiple execution and directories?

Tags: php, shell, cmd, exec, shell-exec

I am trying to Execute a multiple commands in php using exec() and shell_exec but i am getting a null value back which i shouldn't and nothing is happening (if i copy and paste the strings below in the command line it will work fine and accomplish the job needed) this is the commands i am using:

```
$command = "cd /../Desktop/FolderName;";
$command .= 'export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`;';
$command .= 'Here i execute a compiler;';
```

and then i use the escapeshellcmd()

```
$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($command);
```

then

```
shell_exec($escaped_command);
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong and i also tried escapeshellarg() instead of escapeshellcmd()?

**Solution: the Problem was the permission of the execution compiler for other owners is non and this was the problem.
because when you are using `exec()` function in php the owner of the file will be www-data so you need to give permission for the www-data either from the ACL of ubuntu or whatever linux based operating system(you can know the owner by doing this `exec('whoami')`), or by the files you need to execute.**

Comment: Do you really mean `/../Desktop/FolderName`?  Because that's the same as `/Desktop/FolderName`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: it is the same as /Desktop/FolderName and it is what i want but this doesn't effect anything because it is still changing the directory to the folder i need

Comment: i would always use the full, not relative, path for such things.

Comment: why would you escape the command? isnt the entire point to execute the command? escaping prevents execution.

Comment: i have tried without escaping but still the same problem is occurring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry my bad English)
On Linux you can add your Commands in a Shell Script.

You can put this in any file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /../Desktop/FolderName
export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`
EXECUTE COMPILER
```

And save this as fille.sh

Then, add execution permissions:
    chmod +x path/to/file.sh

From PHP, you can call this Script executing:
    shell_exec('sh path/to/file.sh');

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is still not working, should i enable shell_exec() function from somewhere ??

Comment: Have you tried executing the Shell Script rfom outside the PHP Script?

Comment: yes and it works fine. i am researching and i found some people talking about enabling and disabling the exec() function. if the safe mode is on but the safe mode is off in my php.ini. and it is still not working

Comment: Tell me if PHP is showing warnings or errors. If not, look at PHP Error Logs.

Comment: your way work perfectly but the problem was different. thank you for your help anyways